# Adding xing/XNGAPIClient causes errors

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added `xing/XNGAPIClient` pod into a project file that already contains around 20 libraries and when I imported  `"XNGAPI.h"` in AppDelegate.h it shows about 20 errors in `AFNetworking` files i.e in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManeger.h` and `AFHTTPSessionManager.h` 
[image: errors]
Any solution for this.
Thanks!